# Find two discontinuous functions whose product is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, functions, notation, continuity, examples-counterexamples

Find $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is not continuous at 0, $g$ is not continuous at 3, and $f(x)g(x)$ is continuous everywhere.

1. What does $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ mean? Does it necessarily mean that the domain of the function is $\mathbb{R}$?
2. Where do I start to solve this problem? I was thinking $f(x)= \frac{x-3}{x}$ and $g(x)=\frac{x}{x-3}$ but is it correct if $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Does $R$ represent the real numbers?  If so, instead of R, try typing $\text{ \mathbb{R} }$.  This will give you $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Also, the notation $f : R \to R$ is a **function** (called $f$) that takes as input values from $R$, and spits out values in $R$.  In general, $h : X \to Y$ is a function (called $h$) that takes as inputs values from the set $X$ and spits out as outputs values from the set $Y$.

Comment: So, to solve this problem, you need to find a function $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ and a function $g : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ such that $f$ is not continuous at $0$, $g$ is not continuous at $3$, and $f(x)g(x)$ is continuous everywhere.  The nice thing about functions from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$ is that we can visualize them.  These are the functions you used in calculus!  You can draw them in the $XY$-plane.

Comment: Can you think at least of an example of a function $f$ from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ which is not continuous at $0$?

Comment: I need more details. I can't figure it out.

Comment: The problem with $f(x)=\frac{x-3}x$ is the it is not defined for all real numbers. But for example
$$f(x)=
  \begin{cases}
    \frac{x-3}x & \text{if }x\ne0, \\
    1 & \text{if }x=0.
  \end{cases}
$$
would be a function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$. Where is this function continuous and where not? Can you somehow use this example to get $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ as required?

Comment: I can't figure out. Could you just give me the answer?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Find functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ such that their product $f(x)g(x)$ equals the constant function $0$ but where $f(x)$ is discontinuous at $x = 0$ and $g(x)$ is discontinuous at $x = 3$.

Comment: My mistake, I misread the question. I was under the assumption that $f$ and $g$ were functions undefined at $0$ and $3$

Comment: @Axoren Comment deleted. :)